# Sublime Text 2 - Populate "default" autocomplete list

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2, maxscript

I've been doing a lot of MaxScript lately and have mashed together (from an attempt [here](http://www.scriptspot.com/forums/3ds-max/general-scripting/sublime-text-editor-mxs-support#comment-20141)) a ST2 plugin for evaluating scripts from ST.

I've got the syntax highlighting working as well as evaluating the whole file and the current selection, but what I need (due partly to my bad memory and also the gigantic number of MaxScript built-in functions, not to mention those exposed by other plugins I'm using) is for the autocomplete list to be populated initially by a separate text file containing the built-in function names (generated by [these instructions](http://www.scriptspot.com/forums/3ds-max/general-scripting/sublime-text-editor-mxs-support#comment-20136)) and then the file's own names.

The text file is of the following format:

```
...
<function name>
polyOps.createShapeFromEdges
polyOps.startCutEdge
polyOps.selectByID
polyOps.attachList
polyOps.startExtrudeEdge
...
```

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [completions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html) docs have all the information you'll need. Briefly, `.sublime-completions` files are JSON-formatted resources that can contain either simple completions or snippets. For example, a simple completions list using your given terms would look like this:

```json
{
    "scope": "source.maxscript",

    "completions": [

        "polyOps.createShapeFromEdges",
        "polyOps.startCutEdge",
        "polyOps.selectByID",
        "polyOps.attachList",
        "polyOps.startExtrudeEdge"
    ]
}
```

If you would like to use [snippet syntax](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) for more complex auto-completion (for example, to fill in default values for a function), it would look something like this:

```json
{
    "scope": "source.maxscript",

    "completions": [

        { "trigger": "myfunc", "contents": "my_function(${1:param}=${2:value})$0" },

        "polyOps.createShapeFromEdges",
        "polyOps.startCutEdge",
        "polyOps.selectByID",
        "polyOps.attachList",
        "polyOps.startExtrudeEdge"
    ]
}
```

Once you have your completions set up, save the file as `Packages/User/LanguageName.sublime-completions` where `LanguageName` is the name of your `.tmLanguage` file, and you should be all set. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks you so much, sorry it took so long to respond, busy using new scripts! Thanks again!